# Cakephp 3 update with join

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In my cakephp3 first i join a table in model that is

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'className'=>'Users',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_id',
    ]);
}
```

and when i update from controller using this code

```
 $query=$this->Leaves->query();
        $query->contain(['Users'])
        ->update()
        ->set(['admin_noti_status' => 0])
        ->where(array('Users.company_id' => 6))
        ->execute();
```

it shows me an error that is

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.company_id' in 'where clause'
```

But this column is exists in users table.

Answer (score 0):

Joins in update statements are only supported in Mysql, that was the reason the CakePHP ORM does not support that out of the box. Instad you can use the `from` method or use a subquery.

Using from:

```
$query->update()
->from(['u' => 'users'])
->where(['u.company_id' => 6])
->andWhere(['u.id = Leaves.user_id'])
```

Comment: i edit query this 
$query=$this->Leaves->query();
        $query->update()
            ->from(['u' => 'Users'])
            ->set(['Leaves.admin_noti_status' => 0])
            ->where(['u.company_id' => 6])
            ->execute();
That seem the same error as before

Comment: same as before Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.company_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: in your example there you use only one table,but i have two,one will be updated depend on another table.

Comment: I don't understand why you get an error saying "Users.company_id" if my example does not say "User." anywhere...

Comment: for your example it shows u.company_id column not found

Comment: This didn't work for me and resulting `$query` was still being executed on it's original table, the `from()` call seemingly did nothing